# Laravel 5.4, allow the user to only favourite something once so it does not get added to their list twice?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a working favourite system in my application, that allows the users' to favourite a charity and these favourites are displayed to them on another page.

The only problem is that the user is able to favourite the same charity multiple times, how could I limit this to just once and then maybe tell the user that they already have favourited this?

Comment: When adding the favourite check if the users already has a favourite if he already has return an error. If not add his favourite?

Comment: @Ken How would this work in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

On your user object create a method `public function hasFavourite($item)`

This will call something like this

```
return $this->favourites()->where('key', $item->key)->count() !== 0;
```

in your controller you can now check if the user has a favourite

```
... 
if (! $user->hasFavourite($item)) {
    session()->flash(...);
    return back();
}

... continue as usual
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!